# How do I create an observable that fires on changes made to an array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an angular app where I want to have a service that pulls down a couple MB's of data from a rest service as the app initializes.  I then want to update that array through other components in the app.  Is there a way I can create an observable from the array and have it fire the newly updated array to the subscriptions whenever the array changes.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

I was thinking of using a behaviorSubject but I'm not sure if that's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a BehaviorSubject to send out change notifications. But depending on what you are doing with the data, you may not have to.

If you have a property in your service that holds that data and the components are binding to that data, then Angular's change detection will automatically notify the components when the data is changed.

I have a simple example here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

Comment: Thanks @DeborahK, this won't update automatically though right?  I would have to call getValue() again to update the values.  With a behaviorSubject I could subscribe to it and get real time updates.

Comment: Yes, it will update automatically if they are bound. The change detection does that.